# Munin-node plugins on Debian 10 cannot read from home directories. Debian 9 works fine

Tags: debian, munin

I am on a completely default Debian Buster installation.  I have installed munin-node, which reports itself as version 2.0.49.

I have a custom plugin in `/etc/munin/plugins`.  It is a shell script that simply cats a value from a file a user's home directory: `/home/peter/value.txt`.

I can `netcat localhost 4949` to interact with the munin node.

If I issue a `list` command then my plugin *is* included along with all the defaults, so munin-node does recognize that the plugin exists and is executable, etc.  But when I try to run the plugin by issuing a `fetch` command, I get a permission-denied error when the plugin tries to open the file in the user's home directory.  To reiterate; the plugin *itself* executes, but fails to read the file in the home directory.

Some facts:

- **It works on Debian 9 (Jessie)**, where munin-node reports itself as version 2.0.33-1.
- If I hack the plugin to print a hardcoded value, it works.
- The file in the user's home directory has permissions `-rw-r--r--`.  The home directory itself has permissions `drwxr-xr-x`.
- If I `munin-run` the plugin from the command line as root, it works correctly.
- If I move `value.txt` to `/etc/munin/plugins` or `usr/share/munin/plugins` then it works.
- Google suggests that if a plugin works with `munin-run` and not with `munin-node` then SELinux is likely to blame.  I am not running SELinux, AFAIK.
- If I `service munin-node stop` and run `munin-node` manually on the command line as root, it works correctly.
- `htop` shows that the plugin is run as root.  I can add an entry to `/etc/munin/plugin.conf.d` and have it run as the user whose home directory it is, but that has no effect.  (By which I mean; I can see that the plugin is now running *as that user*, but it still gets a permission-denied error).

I believe there is something about the way the service is started by Debian's `/etc/init.d/munin-node` scripts that is causing this.  Possibly AppArmour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is that the munin-node package in Debian 10 includes `/lib/systemd/system/munin-node.service`, which sets `ProtectHome=true`.  Debian 9's munin-node package does not have this file.

Setting `ProtectHome=read-only` is one solution, or even `ProtectHome=false` to include write access.  However the `ProtectHome` flag exists for good reasons.  Arranging for the plugin to read its data from elsewhere (outside of `/home`) is arguably a better solution.

See [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=939339) for discussion of the problem as well as the security-vs-convenience tradeoff.

Comment: Thank you. I know I was close as if my plugin-conf.d/munin-node setting for my plugin to run as root was there id get "permission denied" but with it "file not found" whehn accessing files by chance in my home/user dir. it seemed so strange as it should be running as root and no problems, but it was this debian systemd setting blocking it. thanks, i will instead just store my files for munin stats elsewhere.